# Change the icon in Facebook app requests programatically

Tags: facebook, apprequests

I'd like to programatically change the icon I've added a red square around here:

[image: Icon]

By default this is pulled from the app settings. Is there any way to pull a different image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You cannot change your application icon programmatically. It is only possible via application settings.